# A minimal HashTable implementation

Tags: java, hash-map

For an assignment, I wrote a minimal HashTable implementation (it only supports additions; no deletions).

To resolve collisions, it uses Linear Probing (required by the assignment).

I'm looking for general feedback regarding style, practice, and these things specifically:

- I've gotten out of the habit of using `null` to denote an error/lack of result, since the return type of a method returning `null` doesn't give any hints about whether or not the method can fail. As a substitute, I've started using `Optional`s, since its use makes it very clear whether or not the method can fail. There are a few cases in this code where a `null` would otherwise be used, but I opted for using an `Optional`. Are these cases a correct usage?:

  - The underlying array is an `ArrayList` of `Optional`s of Pairs, since any given cell may or may not contain a value.
  - `findNextInsertionPointAfter` returns an `Optional` since the table may be full; in which case there is no next cell to add to.
- I decided to make my own pair class (`KeyValuePair`) to store the key-value-pair. Was this the correct approach to take?
- I figured passing in the hash-function as a lambda to the constructor of `HashTable` was the most flexible way of setting the function. Is my current set-up optimal?
- `HashTable`s `toString` method is my standard concoction when I need to display a sequential container. Unfortunately, it's quite bulky. Is there a better way of setting this up that still gives the neat output?

Sample output from the internal `main` (at the bottom of HashTable.java):

```
[ -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, - ]
[ -, (1,1), -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, - ]
[ -, (1,1), -, -, -, (5,5), -, -, -, -, -, -, - ]
[ -, (1,1), -, -, -, (5,5), -, -, (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), -, -, -, (5,5), -, -, (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), -, -, (5,5), -, -, (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), -, (5,5), -, -, (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), -, -, (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), -, (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), -, -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), (18,18), -, -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), (18,18), (19,19), -, - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), (18,18), (19,19), (20,20), - ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), (18,18), (19,19), (20,20), (111,111) ]
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), (18,18), (19,19), (20,20), (111,111) ]
Table ran out of space!
[ (26,26), (1,1), (39,39), (14,14), (15,15), (5,5), (16,16), (17,17), (21,21), (18,18), (19,19), (20,20), (111,111) ]
```

KeyValuePair.java:

```
package comp272.a2.q4;

//Since Java doesn't have tuples/a standard pair class.
//A "somewhat immutable" K-V-pair. The fields are final, so they can't be
// reassigned, but we aren't defensively copying the values before we return them.
//If the key and value are themselves immutable, so is the pair.
public class KeyValuePair<K,V> {
    private final K key;
    private final V value;

    public KeyValuePair(K k, V v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + key + "," + value + ")";
    }

}
```

HashTable.java:

```
package comp272.a2.q4;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class HashTable<K,V> {

    //The underlying array that the Hash Tables builds on.
    private final ArrayList<Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>>> underArr;

    //The user-supplied hash-function. It should take the key, and the size of
    // the table, and return a hash.
    private final BiFunction<K,Integer,Integer> hashFunc;

    public HashTable(int tableSize, BiFunction<K,Integer,Integer> f) {
        hashFunc = f;

        underArr = new ArrayList<Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>>>(tableSize);
        initArr(tableSize);
    }

    public int tableSize() {
        return underArr.size();
    }

    public boolean hasSpace() {
        for (Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>> optPair : underArr) {
            if (!optPair.isPresent()) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    //Optionally returns the next available cell if one exists
    //I could also return a negative number to represent a full table,
    // but I thought I'd use Optional for consistency.
    private Optional<Integer> findNextInsertionPointAfter(int startI) {
        for (int currentI = startI + 1; currentI != startI; currentI++) {
            //Wrap back to the start if we go off the right end of the table.
            if (currentI >= tableSize()) currentI = 0;

            if (!underArr.get(currentI).isPresent()) {
                return Optional.of(currentI);
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    //Attempts to insert a pair into the table.
    //Fails and returns false if the table is full, else the element is
    // inserted, and returns true.
    public boolean add(K k, V v) {
        int hash = hashFunc.apply(k, tableSize());

        if (!hashIsWithinTable(hash)) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "The computed hash (" + hash + ")"
            + " exceeded the table size (" + tableSize() + ")");

        Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>> foundCell = underArr.get(hash);
        KeyValuePair<K, V> pair = new KeyValuePair<K,V>(k, v);

        int insertIndex = hash;

        if (foundCell.isPresent()) {
            Optional<Integer> nextIndex = findNextInsertionPointAfter(hash);

            if (nextIndex.isPresent()) {
                insertIndex = nextIndex.get();

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        underArr.set(insertIndex, Optional.of(pair));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String separator = ", ";
        String blankCell = "-";

        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder("[ ");

        for (Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>> optPair : underArr) {
            if (optPair.isPresent()) {
                strB.append(optPair.get());

            } else {
                strB.append(blankCell);
            }

            strB.append(separator);
        }

        //Delete trailing separator
        if (!underArr.isEmpty())
            strB.delete(strB.length() - separator.length(), strB.length());

        strB.append(" ]");

        return strB.toString();
    }

    //Populate the table with all empty cells
    private void initArr(int tableSize) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            underArr.add(Optional.empty());
        }
    }

    private boolean hashIsWithinTable(int hash) {
        return hash < tableSize();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashTable<Integer,Integer> hTable =
            new HashTable<Integer, Integer>(13,
                (key, tableSize) -> key % tableSize );

        System.out.println(hTable);

        Integer[] keys = new Integer[] {
                1, 5, 21, 26, 39, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 111, 145, 146
        };

        boolean addSucceeded = hTable.hasSpace();
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length && addSucceeded; i++) {
            addSucceeded = hTable.add(keys[i], keys[i]);
            System.out.println(hTable);
        }

        if (!hTable.hasSpace()) System.out.println(
            "Table ran out of space!");

        System.out.println(hTable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> As a substitute, I've started using Optionals, since its use makes it very clear whether or not the method can fail.

It tells you about the same as a [Nullable](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Nullable.java?r=24) annotation would do, just with some overhead.

> There are a few cases in this code where a null would otherwise be used, but I opted for using an Optional. Are these cases a correct usage?

I personally agree with this wonderful [rant](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/ROx9rGRb6lI/EF0lk8F0N10J) that any use and the mere existence of `Optional` is wrong.

> The underlying array is an ArrayList of Optionals of Pairs, since any given cell may or may not contain a value.

Too bad. That's not what `Optional` is for. It was meant to be used for return values only (that's why it's not `Serializable`).

And you added some 12 bytes per entry.

> I decided to make my own pair class (KeyValuePair) to store the key-value-pair. Was this the correct approach to take?

Not exactly as there's already `Map.Entry`.

> I figured passing in the hash-function as a lambda to the constructor of HashTable was the most flexible way of setting the function. Is my current set-up optimal?

It adds some overhead, but may make sense.

### KeyValuePair

Nothing to say, except for that usually `toString` would use `"="` rather than `","`. Just look at a `HashMap` in debugger.

An immutable `KeyValuePair` makes a lot of sense for an immutable map, but less for a mutable one. That's why `Map.Entry` allows to set the value (but not the key).

### HashTable

```
private final ArrayList<Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>>> underArr;
```

By using an `ArrayList` (which should be declared as `List`) you're adding additional indirection. The same for `Optional`. You gain some flexibility, which you can't use.

- with the size fixed, an array does the job
- `Optional` buys you nothing at all

`underArr` is a terrible name. `table` would do.

---

```
//The user-supplied hash-function. It should take the key, and the size of
// the table, and return a hash.
private final BiFunction<K,Integer,Integer> hashFunc;
```

That's a pain. Letting the user specify a `Function<K, Integer>`  so that they can choose how to hash their values may make sense. Letting them care about the table size is too bad.

Returning `Integer` rather than `int` (see `IntFunction`) means another efficiency loss.

```
public HashTable(int tableSize, BiFunction<K,Integer,Integer> f) {
    hashFunc = f;
```

So `f` or `hashFunc`? Both names are non-optimal (with `f` being terrible for anything but a local variable), using two different names is a sin.

```
    underArr = new ArrayList<Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>>>(tableSize);
    initArr(tableSize);
```

Without `Optional` you could save yourself `initArr` (didn't I say, I hate the name?).

---

```
public boolean hasSpace() {
    for (Optional<KeyValuePair<K, V>> optPair : underArr) {
        if (!optPair.isPresent()) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Do you really traverse the whole table on each insert? Otherwise, I can't see what this method is good for.

But if you traverse the whole table on each insert, then it's the final blow to any efficiency you could gain by hashing.

*...it's getting too long and I'm getting too negative...*

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "there's already `Map.Entry`"? `Map.Entry` is an interface. Did you mean one of `AbstractMap`'s implementations? Or are you suggesting having `KeyValuePair` implement `Map.Entry` for some reason?

Comment: @DanGetz Right, it's just an interface, one should implement (maybe  you want to add `entrySet()` one day). And yes, `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` would be a perfect fit. No idea what I meant, both makes sense (but `SimpleEntry` more).